# Remove rbd image,but lot of rbd_data files still exists

Tags: ceph

I create a cache tier pool and some rbd images,then I write data to images,remove these images,but lot of rbd_data files still exists,this is why?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETZEh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what a cache tier is for, it caches images. You can run `rados -p <poo> cache-try-flush-evict-all` and `rados -p <pool> cache-flush-evict-all` to flush the cache tier.

Comment: I tried the way you did, but the flush failed.

Comment: Please add that output to the question. The exact commands and error messages would be helpful. Also add ‚ceph osd pool ls detail‘